# How to find this Differential Equation ?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find differential equation of a circle in $XY-Plane$ such that it passes through $(-1,1)$ and $(1,1)$

I need some clue please. I am not able to find the general equation. Is it a trick problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Find the equation of the circle. The equation of a circle with centre (g,h) is
$$(x-g)^2+(y-h)^2=r^2$$
Substitute x=1,y=1 and x=-1,y=1 to calculate g and h in terms of r. Differentiate both sides w.r.t x. r will be a constant.

Comment: I tried that, so $r$ will be the only constant we'll need to eliminate ? hence a DE of order 1 right ?

Comment: Yes r is the only constant. And yes DE will be of order 1.

Comment: Ah !! Thanks, let me try that :)